# Can I Change A Reusable Workflow to a :List Workflow

Tags: list, workflow, designer-workflow, reusable

I created a reusable workflow in Designer by mistake. Is there a way to change this to a normal list workflow without recreating it?

Also, how do I access it after publishing it?  I don't see it in my workflows. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you created a reusable workflow you need to add that workflow to the list or library using the Workflow settings page.

Comment: Are you referring to SharePoint or Designer?  Either way, I'm not seeing how to add it.

Comment: Click on the list you want to add. Then open the list settings -> workflow settings -> Add Workflow.

Comment: My new reusable workflow is not there, just my old workflows.

Comment: Go to Site Settings -> Workflow Settings and check if your new workflow is present

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little lame. There are no workflows listed there even though they are listed other places. That has never made sense to me. I had a list open in Designer and imported a Visio workflow, added the fields, saved, and published. Not sure where it went.  It doesn't show up in the Worflows Lists and Libraries of Designer either.

Comment: Make sure you published it to the same site you are looking around. Are you saying after publishing even in the designer you are unable to find it?

Comment: I republished and it finally showed up but is there a way to change it to non-reusable?  Thank you.

Comment: There is no harm in keeping it as a reusable workflow. There is no straight forward way to make it list workflow.

Comment: @Zippy if your issue is resolved then please up vote and mark answer. Thanks!